# Как получить обложку от песни через last.fm api?

Tags: java, android, api

У них сейчас на сайте ремонт. Примеры в документации не доступны.
Пробовал так:

```
Caller.getInstance().setUserAgent("TST");
Caller.getInstance().setCache(null);
Track result = Track.getInfo("исполнитель", "название песни", "ключ апи");
```

Comment: Работает у них всё  [Last.fm Web Services](http://www.last.fm/api/intro)

Comment: чтобы посмотреть пример нужно присоединиться к группе, и это как раз таки и не работает, даже кнопка логин не риагирует

Comment: По ссылке есть примеры XML. Вы их парсите?

Comment: не хочу парсить, там слишком много всего обрабатывать